# Understanding a parameter in C# code

Tags: c#

IntelliSense says that the lambda parameter `ea` is a DownloadStringCompletedEvent Args. Understood, but parameter `s` is only defined as "object s". Can anyone explain the purpose of this parameter?

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, ea) => 
                     { XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(ea.Result);
                        // ... Do something else...
                      };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EventHandlers in .NET are typically of the form

```
void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

The `sender` argument is the object that the event occurred on. Since it can be just about anything, object is used. The EventArgs argument is typically either `System.EventArgs` itself, or a subclass of it. In your case it is a subclass.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK that object s is usually known as the "Sender", hence the s for sender - ie. the object that generate the event, aka, the source.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm waaay too slow in getting answers typed up. Good work, and I believe this is right. Here's the REAL documentation on the the event that's raised, not the handler, and WHY s is the sender: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventargs.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The lambda matches the delegate

public delegate void DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
    Object sender,
    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e
)

Where s is "The source of the event."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.downloadstringcompletedeventhandler.aspx